# how to resize the image and its quality not be change in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am creating an application and want to setup Image . I do not want the images in same size, but same image quality. how to resize that image but same image quality in android ?

i'm using this method to resize the image

```
  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                        .getAbsolutePath());

                int h = myBitmap.getHeight() / 20;
                int w = myBitmap.getWidth() / 20;
                Bitmap scaled =                                           Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, w, h,
                        true);

                imageTab.setImageBitmap(scaled);
```

Comment: you want the Image stretched to imageView's size , without loosing Quality  ?

Comment: @Anil M H for that u have to put image with different sizes in different draw-able folders... need to put one image in each, sized to match the indicated screen density.it will be manged by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement makes no sense. Whenever you resize it the quality will be changed. Downscaling will make your image lose image data like thin lines etc, and upscaling will make your image blurred and lose clarity.

This is because you only have so much image data with you, and you cannot arbitrarily change the amount of data you have to produce good quality images.

That said, using a format like PNG over JPG can help you save some of the quality at least, as JPG compresses the data even more.

Comment: Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
       .getAbsolutePath());

     int h = myBitmap.getHeight() / 20;
     int w = myBitmap.getWidth() / 20;
     Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, w, h,
       true);

     imageTab.setImageBitmap(scaled);

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet ..

```
private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;
    }

BufferedImage resizeImagePng = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
ImageIO.write(resizeImagePng, "png", new File("Image PAth"));
```